# side effect using enquo() and?

Tags: r, dplyr

based on post [link](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#unquoting), I have learnt a way to deal with passing variables as column is to use `enquo()` and `!!`.

example code:

```
aa <- tibble(n1=1:4, n2=2:5)

foo <- function(dat, var)
{
  var1 <- enquo(var)

  dat %>% select(!!var1)
}

foo(aa, `n1`)
foo(aa, `n2`)
```

however, I realised that I can't do below thing with this method

```
v <- `n1`
foo(aa, v)
```

because object `n1` doesn't exist.

Is there a quick remedy?

Comment: Use quote " instead of `

Comment: why do you need backquotes.  just do `foo(aa, n1)`

Comment: it would be the same problem, right? n1 is a column, not an object, and I assume "n1" would not work in enquo()